# Azure Worker Role runs on osFamily="2" (Server 2008R2) but Fails on osFamily="3" (Server 2012)

Tags: azure

We have an Azure worker role - .NET 4.0 - that runs fine when deployed to Azure on osFamily="2" (Server 2008R2).  However, when we deploy with osFamily="3" (Server 2012) and **no other code changes**, the worker role continually recycles with the following 2 errors in the server event logs:

> Faulting application name: WaWorkerHost.exe, version: 6.0.6002.18488, time stamp: 0x505cf7ca
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x5010ab2d
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000189cc
>   Faulting process id: 0xefc
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cdd4318f76d221
>   Faulting application path: E:\base\x64\WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: cf1810b0-4024-11e2-93ec-00155d4250e3
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Stack:
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Any ideas?

UPDATE ------------------   Found a 3rd exception:

> Application: WaWorkerHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>   Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

We are using a certificate in LocalComputer/My to decrypt connection strings.  The certificate gets deployed successfully to OsFamily="2" (Server 2008R2) and has the Worker role user added to the Private Key (verified in RDP session).  However, for OsFamily="3" (Server 2012) - the certificate doesn't get deployed, hence the crypto error.  Following up with Azure support...UGH.

Comment: Does control ever reach your `OnStart()`?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code in the emulator to find what method might be throwing an error?  I am assuming you are using the Azure 1.8 SDK.

Comment: Yes - app gets to OnStart and logs OnStart to Elmah (SQL).  Yes - on the Azure 1.8 SDK and it runs fine in the emulator - no exceptions with either OSFamily selected.

Comment: found the culprit - missed a 3rd exception:

Comment: Well, wrap all stuff you have in `OnStart`() in one large try-catch, then catch and log the exception that is thrown first.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  I've been wrestling with this for a few days now.  Is there a connect bug or something those of us who are affected can track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Azure Support Engineers:

> After digging deeper, I found the difference: In OS Family 2,
>   WaWorkerHost is running by a temporary account (with a GUID name)
>   generated by Role initialization process, this account has permission
>   to access certificate private key; In OS Family 3, WaWorkerHost is
>   running by “NETWORK SERVICE” account, this account doesn’t have
>   private key access permission.
>
> I’m contacting production group, we will investigate this issue
>   deeper. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Was there ever a supported fix for this problem? It's ridiculous that the Worker Role/Web Role doesn't have access to private keys for certs *you* add. This is most definitely a bug!

Comment: Apparently this is a bug that'll be fixed in the next SDK (?) and a work-around is to add `<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />` to your `.csdef` inside of the `<WorkerRole>` or `<WebRole>` node. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14468164/294863)