# Cannot get Azure WCF service to work with Client Certificates

Tags: wcf, azure, certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF service that I want to secure with Client Certificates but I cannot get it to work on Azure.

I removed Azure from the equation by hosting the service on a standard Windows Server on Amazon. I installed both the service and client certificates (none are self-signed) into the Local Machine 'Personal' store on this server including the chained certificates and it all worked as expected, called from my local PC, with the client cert set against the binding/behavior. It did **not** work without the certificate being specified so it definitely worked correctly this way.

I then deployed the service to Azure. The client and server certificates are uploaded to the portal and set in the config against "Local Machine/My" and the CA and root certificates are uploaded and I tried them in various stores including "My", "Trusted" and "CA". Every variation I try, I continue to get "**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'**" called from exactly the same program locally with the only change being the client endpoint address.

As another detail, I can get it to work without certificates so there is no problem with the web service but I am unsure how to work out what is actually happening with the certificate handshake between client and service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got it to work, and have written a guide here: [Blogspot.co.uk](http://lukieb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/finally-azure-with-client-certificates.html)

I'm not sure what I had got wrong before since I have not done anything too weird to make it work. I think perhaps I had a small defect somewhere in configuration that I eventually fixed by starting again. Anyway, it DOES work and provides some useful security on Azure.

Comment: As another point, if you are using App Services instead of Cloud Services, you need to use the Resource Explorer in the App to enable client certificates, otherwise they are not processed by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448689/azure-autoscaling-works-locally-but-not-when-deployed/14468164#14468164) - bottom line, cert in LocalMachine/My and run with elevated privileges in csdef file add:

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

Comment: I got excited there for a moment but I get the same error. I used RDP and PowerShell to check that the certs are all installed on the Azure server and they're all there as expected. I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: check that the user running the app pool has permissions to access the cert (RDP)

Comment: Not sure how to do that in Azure/Windows Server 2012.

Comment: RDP into instance, run MMC, add Certificates snap-in for Local Computer, browse to personal >> certificates, right-click the cert in question >> All Tasks >> Manage Private Keys - username running the app pool should be in the list