# In which repository is the visual studio part of the azure sdk located?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, sdk

I know that I in the past was able to find the code used for the visual studio part of the azure sdk.

Need to see how visual studio selects certificate and generate remote access passwords when creating cloud services. But I have had no luck searching around in https://github.com/WindowsAzure for it

Need the c# code that selects a certificate and uploads it to azure for the deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the actual SDK source is, but I've posted this solution on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448689/azure-autoscaling-works-locally-but-not-when-deployed/14468164#14468164) and my blog for [Securing Azure ServiceConfiguration values for Enterprise Deployment](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/Securing-Azure-ServiceConfiguration-values-for-Enterprise-Deployment).  Writing the code to encrypt/decrypt is trivial and full examples are provided.  Adding the certificate to a deployment is also easy - just add it to to role settings.  Depending on which SDK you are using, you may have to run with elevated privledges.

Comment: Ye I have also done similar myself and just wanted to check up with how VS was getting things done. Thanks for the link.